# How to add a time delay to an action

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

So I am writing a small slot machine application for my C# class, I have the slot machine coded fairly well, but I was wondering how I would go about adding a time delay to actions. So that 
as my loop ran through I could pause at the end of each iteration, thereby creating a visual update of each slot on my machine for the user to watch

Im not asking for code or a loop on how to achieve this, I can figure that out myself. I just need the method for setting time delays and the parameters of said method.

Comment: Please provide some context. Show us a complete, concise code example that demonstrates what the code currently does, and explain precisely what you'd like it to do instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in two ways, for projects **under** .Net 4.0. Use Thread.Sleep method.

```
Thread.Sleep(int value or TimeSpan here)
```

for projects **over or exactly** .Net 4.0, you may use Task.Delay

```
Task.Delay(10).Wait();

await Task.Delay(10); // for .Net 4.5
```

Comment: Thank you!!! So much!!! We haven't covered this in our book but I knew there was a way!

Comment: @Dlorwisdom `Thread.Sleep` is an interesting suggestion for something that clearly deal with UI... Make sure to ignore that part of answer (if you can't go async route - search for `Timer`).

Answer (score 4):

`using System.Threading;
 Thread.Sleep(x); // put your time in millis here`

Doing the above will pause execution of your thread for however long you specify.